# Recursive depth first search function is not working

Tags: c++, depth-first-search

Here is the code that I tried.

```
class Node 
{
    public:
        char value;
        bool visited;
        vector<Node> adj;
        Node(char v)
        {
            value = v;
            visited = false;
        }
};
void DFS(Node node)
{
    node.visited = true;
    cout << node.value << endl;
    int i;
    for(auto i=node.adj.begin(); i != node.adj.end(); ++i)
    {
        if(!(*i).visited)
        {
            DFS(*i);
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    Node node1('A');
    Node node2('B');
    Node node3('C');
    Node node4('D');
    Node node5('E');
    Node node6('F');
    Node node7('G');
    node1.adj.push_back(node2);
    node1.adj.push_back(node3);
    node1.adj.push_back(node4);
    node2.adj.push_back(node5);
    node2.adj.push_back(node6);
    node4.adj.push_back(node7);
    DFS(node1);
}
```

It is only visiting the nodes in the adj vector of node1. I don't understand why it is doing so. The output I am getting is A,B,C,D which means that DFS(node2) should've been called but it is not visiting the nodes in it's adj vector. If I call DFS(node2) from main() it is giving D E F as output. Can you explain why this code is not working and how I could fix it?

Comment: Right now you push back *copies* of the *original* and unmodified nodes from the `main` function. You need to use *pointers* to get a kind of reference to the original nodes instead of copies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is already suggested that you should use pointers to nodes in the adjacency vector of the node, but then you have to maintain the lifetime of the nodes outside of your graph and you can expect changes on the nodes outside the graph.

You can also keep your node as it is and then work directly on the nodes in the graph.

```
Node node1('A');
node1.adj.push_back(Node('B'));
node1.adj.push_back(Node('C'));
node1.adj.push_back(Node('D'));
node1.adj.push_back(node4);
Node& node2 = node1.adj.front();
node2.adj.push_back(Node('E'));
node2.adj.push_back(Node('F'));
Node& node4 = node1.adj.back();
node4.adj.push_back(Node('G'));
DFS(node1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you debug your code, you will find out that the adj value for node2 and node4 are incorrect. Because you have assigned them in the wrong order. Better to use a pointer or reference for the adj vector, so that the order won't matter anymore.